# Inducing a Julia Task to finish

Tags: http, websocket, julia

I have an application where I have a middleman function that is listening on a Julia `Channel` for data and immediately writing the data to an `HTTP.WebSocket` object. There is some sort of client at the other end of the websocket, let's say it's JavaScript running in a browser. I have created a `Task` object that is bound to the middleman function. I would like the client to, say, close the websocket, and have that action cause the `Task` to finish. Here's what my middleman looks like:

```
function listener(port::Int64, channel::Channel)
    HTTP.listen(Sockets.localhost, port) do http::HTTP.Stream
        if HTTP.WebSockets.is_upgrade(http.message)
            HTTP.WebSockets.upgrade(http, binary=true) do ws
                try
                    while !eof(ws)
                        _ = readavailable(ws)
                        bytes = take!(channel)
                        write(ws, bytes)
                    end
                catch err
                    if isa(err, InvalidStateException)
                        @info "Channel for $port is closed, exiting"
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What I see is that `listener()` reacts to the websocket's being closed - it catches an `InvalidStateException` - but the `Task`'s state remains `:runnable`. You'll notice that I'm currently ignoring the content of the message sent by the client (`_ = readavailable(ws)`). I've done some experimenting with checking for a special value (e.g. "done"), but haven't had any better luck with that approach than just having the client close the websocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to kill a task from outside a networking task is to send  an interrupt exception.  For example, I wanted to use `Revise` with `Mux` and `Mux` wouldn't remap any functions or lambdas properly unless I restarted `Mux`.  I didn't want to close julia, I just wanted to restart the `Mux.serve` task.

```
global MUX_SERVER_TASK = nothing
function revise_mux_routes(port=8080)
    # println("Revise works!")
    global MUX_SERVER_TASK
    if !isnothing(MUX_SERVER_TASK)
        @async Base.throwto(MUX_SERVER_TASK, InterruptException())
        while !(istaskdone(MUX_SERVER_TASK) || istaskfailed(MUX_SERVER_TASK))
            yield()
        end
        println("killed MUX_SERVER_TASK")
        @show MUX_SERVER_TASK
    end

    MUX_SERVER_TASK = Mux.serve(APP, port; stream=true, readtimeout=0)
    @show MUX_SERVER_TASK
end
```

This same sort of function should work with killing your listen task.

Comment: I've been using a mechanism that uses Base.throwto(task, InterruptException()) after an arbitrary sleep interval (simulating a user interrupt), and it does work. I was hoping for something that responded directly to the client's closing of the websocket. I'm not quite ready to give up on that dream :).

Comment: Related... https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6283